# Displaying a text area on top of an image

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've seen questions for putting an image in a text area, but I have a slightly different problem: I'd like to layer a textarea *on top of* an image. I've tried using the z-index style property but the image - which I fadeIn with jquery - always sits on top of the text area.

Comment: Some code (and a fiddle) would be nice.

Comment: you need to use the images as background then only you can get the text on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it which may be more versatile.

Create a block level container with two child elements, one for the image and one for the text area:

```
<div class="textpanel">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
        <textarea>some text area text...</textarea>
</div>
```

Apply the following **CSS**:

```css
.textpanel {
    position: relative;
}
.textpanel img {
    display: block;
}
.textpanel textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Set `position: relative` on the parent container and then use `position: absolute` to place the the `textarea` over the image.

You can use `rgba` to control the opacity of `textarea` or you can fade the image using your method of choice.

You can also try styling the border to the `textarea` as needed.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ygMZ6/

### How This Works

Setting `position: relative` on `.textpanel` simply sets a reference for any absolutely positioned child elements.

Setting `position: absolute` on `textarea` allows for vertical and horizontal positioning.
A new stacking order is created which is why the textarea appears overlying the image, which
is still in the root level stacking order.

In this case, no need to use `z-index` to alter the stacking order of any elements.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this worked! It seems that without specifying the position attribute, the text area would always be under the image, regardless of the z-index. Note sure if that precisely is the fix, or the container div. Either way, your method worked.

Comment: I added a few comments to explain a bit more how this works.  All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You could always use CSS:

```
textarea{
  background:url('image.png');
}
```

or

```
textarea{
  background-image:url('image.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you would want to do that but here is my thought on this..

Set the background image of the text area then use simple javascript or jquery to implement background fading..

Here are some examples on background images for text areas..
http://www.angelfire.com/nm/thehtmlsource/jazzup/text/textareabgimage.html

Comment: The reason I want to do it is because I want a speech bubble on top of an image (an image of someone saying something). I want to put text in the speech bubble.

Comment: Unfortunately a background image is not going to work, since the text area in the speech bubble is much smaller than the overall background